# Multi dimensional array in python with predefined size

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a multidimensional array with a predefined size. In C I would do the following:

```
int multi_array[5][6][7];
```

How do I create such thing in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ndarray((5,6,7), dtype=int)
```

*note:*  This array will contain whatever junk happened to be in the unallocated memory at the time of creation.  You may prefer to use this form if you are going to populate it with data later, for efficiency.  Otherwise you might prefer to use `np.zeros` instead.

Comment: -1 (sorry); the [`ndarray` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) state: "Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty`" -- you're not really supposed to call the `ndarray` constructor except when inheriting from it, and advising new users to do so is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this.  I have used this form of constructor in a lot of my old code, is there any danger?  It has advantage of more control than `np.empty` and I can't see any obvious disadvantages..

Comment: I don't think there's much danger, it's just that the `ndarray` constructor is reserved for advanced use, not Numpy noobs. I'm not sure what extra control you need; I've got by with Numpy for several years without ever calling the constructor. `np.empty` takes `shape`, `dtype` and `order`. I must admit I never use buffers except at the Cython level using `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData`.

Comment: I think I needed strides once for some reason to do with boost::python and wrapping some performance critical C++ code, but it was years ago and I can't remember the details now

Answer (score 3):

```
np.empty((5, 6, 7), dtype=int)
```

or, if you want it zero-filled,

```
np.zeros((5, 6, 7), dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 1):

keep in mind that `numpy` is a non-standard extension although you can find it on most systems nowadays. If you need to do this in pure python, you may try something like:

```
multi_array = []
for i in xrange(5):
    list2 = []
    for j in xrange(6):
        list3 = []
        for k in xrange(7):
            list3.append(0)
        list2.append(list3)
    multi_array.append(list2)
```

of course a better approach is doing this on the fly (when loading the data or so) as `python` variables are not intended to be declared first as in `C`.